# T-SQL Insert and Update table during selection from it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table with Timestamp column and I select rows from it this way:

```
Select top(@count) * from [table]
Into #Increment
where [Timestamp] > @timestamp
order by [Timestamp]

Select max(Timestamp) from #Increment

Select * from #Increment
```

At the same time a service insert into and update [table]. Sometimes I miss some rows when I select from [table] using selection query presented above. I don't see any reasons for that. How can I get rid of this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What **datatype** is your `timestamp` column??

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a temporary table and are asking why changes to the original source table aren't represented in it?

Comment: marc_s, timestamp datatype (rowversion)

Comment: Gordon Linoff, I save data after selection in my application and then to check data do another selection from old timestamp and timestamp that I get from first selection. Compare records by Id ([table] also contains Id column and another data columns) and some of them are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no order in which rows are returned (each time TOP may return different rows), to keep the order add "order by timestamp DESC" clause.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add it to query. I'll update question, sorry!

Comment: Actually the rowversion column is updated every time the row is modified, so the order by timestamp ASC doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If I add order by desc I'll select top of latest rows but I want to select it from the old one to the new rows. Anyway, why it doesn't make sense? Can you explain the difference between asc and desc order by in this situation, please?

Comment: I am not sure what is your goal? Rowversion field changes any time when row is modified. Using order by ASC you just get the first rows that were only inserted (not updated).

Comment: I have the service which supports information in the actual state. This service selects information from latest timestamp by batches. And there are a lot of services which update information and insert new. Because of that I'm ordering table by timestamp to get rows which were updated or inserted.

Comment: Example: you have 5 rows that were inserted or modified and have timestamp > @timestamp. You select top 3 of them. Then you update 1 row (that has the lowest rowversion), and then you again select top 3. Indeed this updated row will not be returned but was returned in the 1st query.

Comment: I check records which are between two timestamps. In this situation, I'll have only two records to check because one of them was updated. It's okay. But I have a situation when I don't have saved records when I check it. I think selection somehow can miss some rows due to update or insert from another services.